# Preserve indent space for wrapped line in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, indentation, autoindent

I like to print out my code sometimes, so I was wondering if there was a way to get Word (2007 for me) to automatically preserve the amount of tab space for the whole of a wrapped line.

Interestingly, even Visual Studio 2010 doesn't have this option, but a [plugin can be used](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ac95f80f-6cfd-4b67-b0fd-e9c5c8fb27de) to allow this.

[image]

The screenshot above, shows what I want Word to do.

Comment: When you paste your code in from VS, the tab space is not preserved (Note: it is not required to use an extension to get that behavior, a check box must be checked, not quite the biggest deal (it may even be the default, I don't think I changed it, and that is how mine operates)).

Answer (score 0):

The tab space won't be preserved when copying from VS to Word. However perhaps you will have more luck in directly printing from Visual Studio instead. Please see the following link for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/683835/1126985